# Checking if a user is less than 18 years old

Tags: python, python-datetime

Hi im new in programming in python with `datetime` (and in general to be honest).
So im doing a project where I need to check if the user is more than 18 years old. I used `timedelta` to get the difference between today and the birthday and I want to check about month and days as well

I have this code:

```
...
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

...

birthday= request.form.get('birthday')
birth= datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%Y-%m-%d').date()

year= datetime.timedelta(today.year - birth.year)
month= datetime.timedelta(today.month- birth.month)
day= datetime.timedelta(today.day- birth.day)
...
```

For checking the date:

```
...

if year <= datetime.timedelta(18) and month <= datetime.timedelta(0) and day < datetime.timedelta(0):
     flash('must have 18 years old to sign-up', category='error')

...
```

Is this correct? Is there any clearer way to get everything with less code? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: There are various ways to do this, but one way: given the person's birthdate, figure out the date of their 18th birthday. Then simply checking `today>=eighteenth_birthday` will tell you whether they are at least 18 years old.

Comment: Generally though, year-based arithmetic is awkward in `timedelta` because of leap years. If you can use the `dateutil` module it works more neatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how accurate you must be.  The datetime module is perfectly capable of date arithmetic.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

birthday = request.form.get('birthday')
birth= datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%Y-%m-%d')
age = (today-birth).days / 365.25
print(age)
```

Depending on the position of the leap years, this might be a day off.

Alternatively:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
ago = datetime.date(today.year-18, today.month, today.day)
print(ago)

birthday = request.form.get('birthday')
birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%Y-%m-%d')
if birth > ago:
    print("Not yet 18...")
```

Comment: The computation of `ago` in the second snippet will throw if for example `today` is 2024-02-29.

Comment: Yep, there are hacky ways to handle that.  `min(today.day,28)` will get close enough for most purposes.

Comment: Alternatively to compute the 18th birthday: `age18 = birth.replace(year=birth.year + 18)`.  Then do `if today >= age18:`.

Comment: This worked just fine! Just needed to add `.date()` to birth since said it couldn't compare datetime with date, don't know if should happened or not but solve the case anyway. Its perfect this way as i dont use HH-MM-SS in my db table.